# Coincident point of map from mobius to $R^3$

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology

Assume $M$ is mobius. $f:M\rightarrow R^3$ is a  continuous map , and map $\partial M$ to a circle on $xy$-plane ,and $z$ of $f(M)$ is non-negative.How to show that there must be different points $p,q\in intM$ such that  $f(p)=f(q)$ ?

> [image]

Comment: Are you sure that your statement is actually correct? According to wikipedia, there are embeddings of the Moebius strip into $\mathbb{R}^3$ which map the boundary to a circle in a plane.

Comment: Hint. If you glue in a disc on the boundary that lies fully in the lower half space, then you now have an embedding of the real projective plane into $\mathbb{R}^3$. This is supposing that the map into $\mathbb{R}^3$ of the Mobius band has image with non-negative $z$ coordinate (as you seem to have drawn it) - otherwise, as Eric says above, one can embed the Mobius band into $\mathbb{R}^3$ with a round boundary.

Comment: Eric is right and the claim you are trying to prove is wrong. See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1734169/knots-from-the-boundary-of-m%C3%B6bius-strips

Comment: For those wondering, the reason why I think the added assumption about the non-negativity of the $z$-coordinate is implied by the OP is because this is a step that is normally part of the famous proof that every Jordan curve in the plane contains the vertices of a rectangle. The points of the surface are given by taking the mid-point between any two points on the curve and having the height given by the distance between them (non-negative for interior points).

Comment: I voted to close since your question is clearly missing some assumptions. You should also describe what you tried to solve the problem.

Comment: @EricSchlarmann   I am very sorry . And according to (at) Dan Rust , I have edit it .  I don't know I missing some thing (at Moishe Cohen). Because it just be what I feel ,and I am not sure it is right , although I really feel it is right .

Comment: @DanRust  It is interesting that every Jordan curve in the plane contains the vertices of a rectangle . Whether it has other version ? For example , every Jordan curve in the plane contains the vertices of a regular triangle  ? Or  high-dimensional version ?

Comment: @DanRust  According your hint , I think a proof in below answer. But I fail to understand embedding of real projective plane to $\mathbb R^3$ . Do you mean glue a disc and Moebius along their boundary will get $RP^2$ ? How to show it  ?

Answer (score 0):

According to hint of Dan Rust.

Because the $z$ of $f(M)$ is non-negative. So ,we can glue half of sphere along the $\partial f(M)$ and the half sphere lie in the lower half space.

And there is not coincident point , so $f(M)$ like a half sphere . So, the result after gluing is  homeomorphism to $S^2$ . This is equal to say that glue a disc along the boundary of Moebius will get $S^2$. But as we know , $S^2$ and disc are oriented , but Moebius is not . So we get contridiction (because it is equal to say that cutting a disc from $S^2$ , the result is not oriented).

Comment: You did not read my hint carefully enough.